Let $\xi=\left\{\left(a_{n_k}\right)_{k\in N}\right\}$. Prove that $|\xi|=2^{\aleph_0}$
Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$
be a sequence with no repeated elements. Define $$\xi=\left\{\left(a_{n_k}\right)_{k\in N}\right\}$$
as the family of all subsequences of $(a_n)$
. Prove that $|\xi|=2^{\aleph_0}$
.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Can you please write the definition of "partial sequence of a sequence"?

$$\zeta=\left{\left(a_{nk}\right)_{k\in N}\right}$$

You've written $\zeta$ where you presumable mean $\xi?$

Is it supposed to be $a_{n_k}?$

Yeah, a partial sequence is not a normal term. I'd guess you mean subsequences? As written, it could also include permutations.

Sorry I mean subsequence
